# Lambda expression conversion

Tags: c#, lambda

I am a beginner in Linq.

How can I rewrite this lambda expression as a linq compiled query?

```
var query5 = CustomerList.Select((cust, index) =>  new {cust, index})
                         .Where(c =>  c.cust.Country == "USA"  &&  c.index  >  70)
                         .Select(c =>  new { c.cust.CustomerID, c.cust.CompanyName, 
                                            c.index });
```

like

```
var query5 = from c in .......
             where .....
             select c new {....}
```

Comment: That's not a "compiled" query. It's just a different syntax. It doesn't have a technical advantage.

Comment: I don't need technical advantage. Sorry!

Comment: I do feel the Linq syntax is more readable than the lambda variant.

Comment: @Jonathan van de Veen - maybe, but there are quite a few operations that are only available via the lambda syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Well here's the closest query expression syntax:

```
var query5 = from c in CustomerList.Select((cust, index) =>  new {cust, index})
             where c.cust.Country == "USA"  &&  c.index  >  70
             select new { c.cust.CustomerID, c.cust.CompanyName, c.index };
```

Basically the one bit you *can't* do in query expression syntax is the "select including the index" overload. There simply isn't any syntax which translates to that. (The same goes for quite a few other operations - VB's LINQ syntax is richer in this respect, although personally I'm happy with the way that C# does it; it avoids adding too many contextual keywords.)

(As Mehrdad says, this isn't a "compiled" query. In fact the code will be compiled to exactly the same IL.)

Comment: Wasn't aware of an overload that includes an index. Yet another linq mystery resolved :-D